# Default not lazy with exceptions in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want my application to work without lazy load by default. However in some cases (which I want to set explicitly) I need lazy loading.

So, my default conventions are (last line swithes off default lazy loading):

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(driverConfig)
            .Mappings(m => m
                .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Limit>()
                .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<Limit>()
                .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Id"))
                .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())
                .Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"))
                .Conventions.Add(ConventionBuilder.Id.Always(x => x.GeneratedBy.Native()))
                .Conventions.Add(ConventionBuilder.Id.Always(x => x.Unique()))
                .Conventions.Add(Cache.Is(x => x.NonStrictReadWrite()))
                .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
```

And I want this Many relation to be lazy loaded:

```
        HasMany(x => x.TestCaseOrdered).KeyColumn("ProductVariantId").LazyLoad();
```

However, it isn't lazy loaded. I tried to replace DefaultLazy.Never() convention with LazyLoad.Never() but it doesn't work (and I cannot understand the difference).

How can I easily switch off lazy loading for all cases except one concrete?

Comment: it works for me, how do you determine if it is lazyloaded or not?

Comment: While searching for the the test code, where am I checking that found that I'm retrieving them always as non lazy. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was retrieving tests with code:

```
 using (ISession session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            // TODO: Criteria + lazy
            var productVariants = session.CreateCriteria<ProductVariant>().List<ProductVariant>().ToArray();

            // TODO: Lazy loading should be available
            foreach (var product in productVariants)
            {
                var testCaseDataOrders = product.TestCaseOrdered.ToList();
                testCaseDataOrders.Select(x => x.TestCaseData.Id);
            }

            return productVariants;
        }
```

That was the problem